# How to load translations from database after they are imported in LexikTranslationBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.2

I am using [LexikTranslationBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikTranslationBundle) for translate contents in my project. I have been reading carefully the documentation for the bundle and I have setup my project as follow:

```
# LexikTranslationBundle Configuration
lexik_translation:
    fallback_locale: [en]     
    managed_locales: [en, es]
    storage:
        type: mongodb             
        object_manager: default
```

Docs says:

> The bundle overrides the translator service and provides a
>   DatabaseLoader. Database translations content is loaded last so it
>   overrides content from xliff, yml and php translations files. You can
>   also export translations from the database into files in case you need
>   to get translations files with the same content as the database.

Maybe this mean I depends on `.xliff` files and can't load translations directly from DB which sucks.

As a side note I have already loaded all the translations I had in `.xliff` files into the DB so I've removed the `.xliff` files from the project.

I want to manage the translations directly from DB and get rid of the files and I've tried but it doesn't work.

Did I miss something here? How do I load the translations directly from DB?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to remove your `.xliff` files.

The `translator.loader` service will decorated when the container is built, and will try to load use the database value: https://github.com/lexik/LexikTranslationBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Compiler/TranslatorPass.php

So, the problem might has to do with clearing your cache. If you test whether:

1. You are able to make translations via the edit page
2. Manually clear the cache, and play with the cache settings a bit

```
lexik_translation:
    auto_cache_clean: false
    auto_cache_clean_interval: 600
```

see [configuration](https://github.com/lexik/LexikTranslationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#configuration)

Comment: And that's exactly my issue, I don't want to depend anymore on the `.xliff` file. That makes the work "harder" since I have to create the translation on the file, import it to the DB and clear the cache in case I want to use the translation from DB. What I would expect and want is to load the translations directly from DB without need to go thru the file all the time. That way I could delete the `.xliff` file forever and continue having my translations on DB. So your answer doesn't fix my problem.